# from particular section, alignment is not proper.

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am working in a file for one month, but today suddenly from  a particular section alignment is proper. Dont know that whether without my knowledge did any mistake...

Comment: If you having the code can not find the problem, how we without the code could find? Please, give more info.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! As it stands, nobody is going to be able to say anything other than: something in your code is causing the problem. Please create a small, compilable document which we can use to reproduce the error. Copy your file and then start commenting stuff out until the error disappears. Put the last thing you commented back and then repeat until you can't take anything out of the document without the error disappearing. You may realise now what the problem is. If not, post that code here and we can take a look.

Comment: Are you using something like `\centering{...}`...?